# How to export a script written in RStudio including colour-coding, line numbers and formatting?

Tags: r, formatting, format, export, rstudio

I would like to export a script that I have written in RStudio together with the colour-coding, the line numbers and the formatting (indents).
So far, I have only seen the option to print the script in a text format, where I have not line numbers as well as not colours or indents.

Is there any possibility, how I could print or export my script in a way that the original layout is kept without having to reformat it using a program like MS Office Word?

Thank you very much for your help already in advance!

Comment: `knit` it to pdf using `eval = FALSE` and `echo = TRUE`

Comment: I have unfortunately no idea how the knitting works. Is this a function that I have to enter?

Comment: You can go through Rstudio tutorial: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-1.html